# Xcode "file not found with <angled> include; use "quote" instead

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, boost, header

I am trying to include boost library to xcode, and xcode is complaining about  include.

I am a mac user, and the library is under

```
/usr/local/boost_1_62_0
```

Under Build Setting, I added the path for Header Search Paths and User Header Search Paths.

In .cpp, I tried to use

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
```

but it threw an error saying fix the  to "quote". Once I did that, it's complaing about the libary files themselves have to fix  to "quote", as attached picture shows.

Any suggestions??

[image: error message]

Comment: What specific paths did you set? Is the file `asio.hpp` in `/usr/local/boost_1_62_0/boost/asio.hpp` or somewhere else, such as `/usr/local/boost_1_62_0/include/boost/asio.hpp`?

Comment: The file is at /usr/local/boost_1_62_0/include/boost/asio.hpp. I added /usr/local/boost_1_62_0/include to Header Search Paths and User Header Search Paths.

Answer (score 0):

Add `/usr/local/boost_1_62_0` to `System Header Search Paths` instead of `User Header Search Paths`. Then you can write `#include <boost/asio.hpp>` without any problems.

## Explanation:

`#include <filename>` is for including system library headers while `#include "filename"` is for user-defined headers.

All of the instances of `#include <boost/filename.hpp>` in the Boost header files expect `boost/filename.hpp` to be in the system header search path, which isn't the case when you just set `User Header Search Paths` to `/usr/local/boost_1_62_0`.